# Android - onKeyDown called from within onReceive

Tags: android, android-intent

I am totally new to Android development and Java development so please excuse my idiotic question :)

I want to setup an app that stops the SMS sound when a button is pressed.

So far I was able to setup an SMSReceiver that sees when an SMS is being received and does the actions it's told. Here's the code:

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.AudioManager;

public class SMSReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager)context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    switch (audioManager.getRingerMode()) {
    case AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE:
        audioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        audioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE);
    break;
    case AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL:
        audioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        audioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL);
    break;
    }
  }
}
```

Now, what I need is to do the actions inside the onReceive only when the volume down button is pressed (or any other button for that matter).

I tried to add an onKeyDown method... but I'm not able to sort it out :(.

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 1):

Edit: made some changes

```
public static Boolean buttonPressed = false; 

 //put these 2 methods inside your current activity

@Override //important!
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN)){
            buttonPressed = true;
        }
         return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);;
    }

@Override
    public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN)){
            buttonPressed = false;
        }
         return super.onKeyUp(keyCode, event);;
    }
//This inside your receiver class
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
{
    if(buttonPressed){
        //your code
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I tried it, but I can't seem to get it to work. It always returns buttonPressed as false, it does not wait for the key input. Not sure if I'm doing something wrong... Also, if I use @Override with onKeyDown or onKeyUp I get an error: "The method onKeyUp(int, KeyEvent) of type SMSReceiver must override or implement a supertype method". From what I read this can only be used if I extend the Activity class (I'm extending BroadcastReceiver)... not sure if that's true or not.

Comment: Yes you are right. You should put those 2 methods inside your (current) activity! If you don't it's like you made your own useless method and not using the one by Android as a child. I assume you can figure out the rest :).

Answer (score 1):

As I understood the problem you can use the following way: when button changes its state - write boolean flag in user preferences. When SMS comes you can check the flag from preferences .

Answer (score 1):

The code:

```
if(buttonPressed){
    //your code
}
```

Should actually be:

```
if(currentActivity.buttonPressed){
    //your code
}
```

Since it can't resolve buttonPressed from another class